# Use SQL driver from buildpack to deploy app with multiple datasources on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, mysql, cloud-foundry

I have a war application that I wish to deploy and configure with multiple mysql services. When the application is bound to one mysql service, PCF automatically configures the datasource using the SQL driver downloaded by the java-buildpack. I want to avoid having to package the driver within the war file. Is there a way to use the driver from the buildpack without autoconfiguration?

The [java-buildpack documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-maria_db_jdbc.md) seems to suggest that if the service is named or tagged with "mysql" then the driver will be downloaded and placed on the classpath:

> A user-provided MariaDB or MySQL service must have a name or tag with mariadb or mysql in it so that the MariaDB JDBC Framework will automatically download the JDBC driver JAR and place it on the classpath.

However both of my services are tagged with "mysql":

```
"name": "database1",
"tags": [
  "mysql",
  "relational"
]
```

But when the application is started return the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And when staging the app, the JDBC driver is not downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation link you referenced](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-maria_db_jdbc.md) also lists this requirement for the functionality to execute:

> Existence of a single bound MariaDB or MySQL service and no provided MariaDB or MySQL JDBC JAR.

The key word there is **single**. That is why it's not working when you have two services bound.

I'm not sure there's much you can do. It'll work when there's only one MySQL service bound, but not more than one. That's the defined behavior.

Options going forward: file a Github issue and ask to support your use case, package the JDBC driver with your app.